# How can I count the online users in my application?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am using my own system to handle user authentication and the database is maintained in mysql.

Now, when I see something like

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
```

I want to know how I can get the number of users, using mysql. I set, in web.config, a database that has all tables generated, but I still get `0` when I call this predefined function.

Now, I have a separate database in mysql that maintains roles. It works because they have generated tables. Now I want to know how I can get the count of all users, including anonymous.

Comment: did you set up the membership provider in your web.Config file ?

Comment: "I am using my own system to handle user authentication" - does that mean a Custom MembershipProvider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try adding this to your global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = 0;
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] + 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] - 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

I found it here:

http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-show-number-of-online-users-visitors-for-ASP-NET-website.aspx

This basically tells you how many sessions are currently active in your application regardless of whether they are logged in. You can modify this to include details about exactly which users are logged in and it's independent of whatever system you use for membership.

Answer (score 1):

If you've written your own 'system' to handle authentication, then you'll have to write your own membership provider in order to take advantage of the `MembershipProvider` defined methods.

Here's an overview of building your own provider from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx).

One word of caution - the number of methods that you have to implement is pretty large (and some are fairly useless, IMHO).  I've written a few over the years, and usually we don't use a number of the methods, so we end up with a few "NotImplemented" methods which do nothing.  You may end up with some clutter in your membership class if you go this route.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!