# When user logsoff, application["Usersonline"] dont decrease

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I'm using the code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687066/how-can-i-count-the-online-users-in-my-application).

When a user login it correctly ad +1 to the value, but when users logout it dont decrease the value. Can someone tell me what the reason for that is?.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Application["OnlineUsers"] = 0;   
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Lock();
        Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] + 1;
        Application.UnLock();
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Lock();
        Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] - 1;
        Application.UnLock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not counting the number of logged-in users, you are counting the number of sessions. Before you are logged on, you already have a session, and after you log off, you still have a session, unless you destroy it.

You could force the session to end by invoking `Session.Abandon` in your log off code, possibly in your `AccountController`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I added `Session.Abandon()` to my logout and it still dont decrease the Count when someone logout, Its standart mvc, havent changed anything yet

Comment: Are you sure `Session_End` is called?

Answer (score 1):

The [session_end](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx) event fires whenever a Session ends, not when a user logs out.

A session ends:

1. After a timeout has occurred and the server has not received a request for that session.
2. `Session.Abandon` has been called.

When you log a user out they still have a session but that session is now unauthenticated.

You can call `Session.Abandon` to force the End event to be called. Note, however that the session End event will only be triggered if the session is stored InProc (from `HttpSessionState.Mode`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in built ASP.NET membership provider, then there is a method `Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()`.